# Nativescript Playground and Vuex

Tags: vue.js, nativescript, vuex, nativescript-vue

I'm having trouble to run a NativeScript App on the **Playground** using Vuex.

I've already added the NPM package on the project. And modified my imports from:

```
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'
```

to

```
import { mapGetters } from '../vuex'
```

But it doesn't solved the problem.

Then, I've removed all the mapGetters, mapActions from the code. Now it calls the store directly:

```
return this.$store.getters.[getterName];
```

However, when I scan the QR code, the error message still says:

```
Error: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Failed to find module: "vuex", relative to: app/tns_modules/
```

As this is on the browser, I don't know how to modify or edit the code to reference the Vuex modules.

I've also checked [this playground Vue + Vuex](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=vbL0WB&v=16) sample code. And it runs without problem.

Am I missing something?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Would you mind sharing the playground example where it doesn't work?

Comment: Can you share your import? When I had used "from 'vuex'" it failed too, but "from './vuex'" worked.